# How to add multiple tags to a post in Tumblr using the API with PHP?

Tags: php, tumblr

I am posting on Tumblr using its API. I can successfully post and add a single tag to any post but I am having trouble while adding multiple tags.

This is what they suggest on their guide:

```
{
"response": {
"posts": [
     {
        "blog_name": "blogname",

        "type": "text",
        "tags": [
           "tumblrize",
           "milky dog",
           "mini comic"
        ],
        "title": "A title",
        "body": "Some text for the post"
     },
     ...
  ]
 }
}
```

I do the following in PHP:

```
$data = array('title' => 'My Title', 'body' => 'My Content', 'tags' => 'A Single Tag');
$client->createPost($blog_n, $data);
```

To use multiple tags I wrote the following code:

```
$data = array('title' => 'My Title', 'body' => 'My Content', 'tags' => array('A', 'Single', 'Tag'));
```

but that raises an exception.

Can anyone please help me to understand how to post multiple tags.

This is the exception I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Tumblr\API\RequestException: [500]:
>   Internal Server Error
>
> thrown in
>   /home/freadioc/public_html/socialmedia/tumblr/lib/Tumblr/API/Client.php

[Link to the documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).

**UPDATE**

After the suggestion in the answer below, I used the following code:

```
$data = array('title' => 'My Title', 'body' => 'My Content', 'tags' => 'Multiple', 'Tags'));
```

Using the code above only results in one tag attached to the post i.e. `Multiple`. I think that's because the associative array itself has comma separated values.

Comment: "that raises an exception"  And what exactly would that exception be?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I always accept answers when they solve my problem. :)

Comment: @PatrickQ I have added the exception to question details. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is what they suggest on their guide:

No, it isn't. That's the JSON data structure you can expect to *get back* from the API when you *read* post information. In that case, the `tags` property will be an *array* of tags.

You want to *make* a post here however, and that means the correct documentation section is https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

And as can you see there, it describes the request parameter `tags`as follows:

> tags | String | Comma-separated tags for this post

So you have to pass a *string*, not an *array*.

---

> This is the exception I get:

And that's not true either ...

No, this is not the exception you got, it is the fatal error you get because you *neglected* to catch the exception.

You should go read up on how to use try/catch to properly handle exceptions, and how to get a look at what error information they actually contain: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

---

Edit:

> After the suggestion in the answer below, I used the following code:
>
> ```
>   $data = array('title' => 'My Title', 'body' => 'My Content',
>                 'tags' => 'Multiple', 'Tags'));
> ```

Nobody suggested that.

You have not added two values for the key `tags` here, but only one (`Multiple`) - and then a completely independent new array element with the value `Tags`.

A string with comma-separated tags is simply that - **a string**:

```
$helloIAmAString = 'with,comma,separated,tags';
```

Comment: Thanks CBroe but the PHP code already contains the comma separated `array`. Adding comma separated tags won't be possible here. :)

I tried it but the post just gets the first tag in the list.

Comment: _"but the PHP code already contains the comma separated array"_ - yes, and that is the problem. It has to be a string, not an array.

Comment: I am adding more details about the issue to the question. :)

Comment: I have added more details at the end of question.